# Possibility to translate all mouse clicks with shifted coords. (Or touchscreen issue with non native screen resolution.)

Tags: windows, touchscreen, mouse-click, coordinates

I bought new notebook with touchscreen (dreams come true!), and in addition to the work I want to play old games on it. My video card fully supports non native screen resolutions and displays the image in the center of screen (don't stretch the picture). So anything just fine except for one.

Unfortunately for fullscreen apps, when resolution is non native, any touchscreen interaction is shifted like this:

[image]

So here the main question: **Is it possible to translate all mouse clicks positions with shifted coords?**

Or any other solution? Touchscreen driver update? (But I have not found any by myself and even not found my touchscreen listed in device manager or manufacturer info into user guide.) AutoHotkey script? Something else?

*Additional info:*

Hardware: Sony VAIO svT1312V1R/S with unknown embedded touchscreen.
Software: Microsoft Windows 8 (x64)

I need just "clicks". No modern multi-pulti-fulti-mega-ultra-super-zooming-stretching-jumping-fingerdancing-planting-touchscreen features. Oops, sorry. I forgot that I don't know how to write jokes on english. Too bad. Just make a edit and insert here something more funny and clever.

Comment: (+1) - that should help getting to the required 10...

Comment: Great.  Have a look at my answer below -- could it be as simple as that?

Answer (score 0):

Isn't there a calibration utility?  Something provided by the graphics card manufacturer?

I have a touchscreen laptop as well (Windows 7 though).

If you can find the Control Panel in Windows 8 (try going to the standard desktop and running `control`), then there ought to be a number of panels that involve touch / tablet settings.

On mine there is:

```
 Tablet PC Settings -- here there is `Calibrate...` button for touch screens.
```

Comment: First of all thanks for answer. Unfortunately it's not that simple. I already tried to run default OS calibration, but when the game change resolution, the coordinates of the calibration are also become different. I search and walked through all video options once again (Intel graphics panel) and did not find anything about touchscreen. It's also sad, because USB mouse works fine on screen and I hoped that touchscreen can work simply as mouse. But not. I will try something else when I got free time.